# Appcelerator Studio undefined1 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: ide, appcelerator, crash-reports, appcelerator-studio

My Appcelerator Studio suddenly just crashed and can't open or use it anymore. I tried UNINSTALLING and REINSTALLING it, but with no luck.

Any thoughts about this? Please check the [Crash error report here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpajX.png)

### System Information

OS: MAC(OS X El Capitan v10.11.3)
Memory: 4GB RAM

### Crash report

```
undefined:1

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
at Object.parse (native)
at Object.readConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appcelerator/lib/util.js:720:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appcelerator/bin/appc:96:23)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
at startup (node.js:139:18)
at node.js:968:3
```

Comment: can you please add the `ti info` output. Looks more like a Node problem (e.g. wrong version)

Comment: @miga, I cannot use CLI on this, it always gives me that error above. The correct answer is already posted by Kondal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is an incompatibility between your CLI version and Node version.

What's the node and CLI version which you are running now?

Node 4.2 and higher is required to run the latest Studio 4.8.0/CLI 6.0/SDK 6.0. Ideally, Studio Mac installer would have taken care of this but it didn't happen in your case.

To make it work in your case, follow the instructions from here for clean installation of Node and CLI, then run the studio.

https://medium.com/all-titanium/reinstalling-appcelerator-titanium-on-mac-from-scratch-9a2bb6b9b629#.d0k1wzt3z

Comment: Thanks!!! I already have solved this problem based on the link you provided.

Basically, the culprit is the "~/.android" directory. It seemed to be corrupted during the auto update of the IDE and such. But to be safer and straightforward, it is better to have the clean reinstallation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error with Appc 7.1.2 -- here's what I learned.

The specific error occurs at `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appcelerator/lib/util.js:720`

For other Appcelerator versions, the line number within `util.js` may be different.

I opened `util.js` in an editor and added a line to figure out what's going on:

```
console.log(cf);
```

Now I could see which config file it was attempting to read, which in my case turned out to be:

```
~/.appcelerator/appc-cli.json
```

This .json file was empty. Upon deleting this file, the error went away.

Now run `appc setup` and enter your credentials and answer the other prompts, and that will re-create and re-write `appc-cli.json`.